# GAE Full Text Search not finding imports in production

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm having issues getting the full text search to work in the GAE production environment. It works fine on my dev machine, but when I deploy it to production, I'm getting this error:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'search' or call 'IndexDocument()' was not found.
```

This looks to be a runtime issue where it can't find the correct class, but I have the appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.0.jar included in WEB-INF/lib so I was assuming that when deploying to prod, it would be using that version of GAE. Am I missing something on how GAE deploys libs to prod? GAE SDK 1.7 should be available in production now right?

These are my imports:

```
  import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.Document;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.Field;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.GeoPoint;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.Index;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.IndexSpec;
import com.google.appengine.api.search.SearchServiceFactory;

//my instantiation
private static final Index INDEX = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService()
              .getIndex(IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("shared_index"));
```

It does appear to be using version 1.7.0. Here is my logging of the version that I'm using and the stack trace of the error right after it:

```
E 2012-08-07 19:30:37.352

version: Google App Engine/1.7.0

W 2012-08-07 19:30:37.702

com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'search' or call 'IndexDocument()' was not found.
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:782)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:824)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.success(RpcStub.java:809)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:893)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:798)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1059)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:907)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2255)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2062)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2000(RpcNetChannel.java:143)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3117)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:599)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:417)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:578)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1002)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:136)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1855)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure having appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.0.jar included in WEB-INF/lib will deploy it as that version.

If you have using eclipse, have you selected a 1.7 sdk from *preferences-->google-->appengine*

Also, how are you deploying?  If you are using a command line, make sure you are using the /1.7sdk/bin/appcfg file to do the uploading.  If you are using eclipse, then set the preferences as above.

NEVERMIND THE ABOVE...

I think you need to build your IndexSpec

```
private static final Index INDEX = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService()
              .getIndex(IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("shared_index").build());
```

Comment: Good thoughts, but it is using version 1.7 for sure. I edited my question above with the actual logging of the version in production which is 1.7.0. I am also deploying using the eclipse GAE plugin.

Comment: @DavidB please see my edit.  I think you need to call .build()

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the suggestion. Strange that the same error doesn't occur in the dev environment. It must have something to do with how the GAE instances are instantiated in the distributed/production environment.